# Set a limit on the amount of text entered into Set /P

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I use `set /p newname=` here:

[image]

I need to set a limit on `set /P` to prevent this issue.

When the character limit is reached, it needs to prevent entering more text.

Comment: Need more info about what your are doing, what is the product in the image, and how the problem arrives.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your best bet in this situation would be to use a variable substring like this:

```
@echo off

set /p "newname=yourinput "

wmic useraccount where name='currentname' rename %newname:~0,7%
```

A variable substring lets you specify how many characters in a variable to skip and/or extract. In the specific example above, when the `%newname%` variable is used, we specify `%newname:~0,7%` - which means don't skip any characters (`~0`) and only use the first seven characters. Also keep in mind if you're modifying system settings, usernames, hostnames, etc. via variables you may also want to loop through the variables and get rid of any characters that will behave poorly in your environment (though usually the command will fail up-front due to syntax/invalid character issues).

Reference: [variable substrings](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Comment: i already did it myself... if i write 11 or more characters on the box it is warning as i want when i pressed ENTER. i just talking about overflow characters from that picture. you see...